# SQL Query to select each row with max value per group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm very new to SQL and this one has me stumpted.  Can you help me out with this query?

I have the following 2 tables:

TABLE 1: IssueTable

```
Id   | RunId | Value
---
1    | 1     | 10  
2    | 1     | 20  
3    | 1     | 30  
4    | 2     | 40  
5    | 2     | 50  
6    | 3     | 60 
7    | 4     | 70 
8    | 5     | 80 
9    | 6     | 90
```

TABLE 2: RunTable

```
RunId     | EnvironmentId
---
1         | 1
2         | 3
3         | 1
4         | 2
5         | 4
6         | 2
```

I need the IssueTable rows that represent the Max RunId grouped by the EnvironmentId in the RunTable.  The result I would need from the tables is:

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Id   | RunId | Value | EnvironmentId
---
4    | 2     | 40    | 3
5    | 2     | 50    | 3
6    | 3     | 60    | 1
8    | 5     | 80    | 4
9    | 6     | 90    | 2
```

So only the rows with the most recent/highest RunId from the RunTable per EnvironmentId.  For example, for the EnvironmentId of "1", I only want rows that contain a RunId of "3" because the most recent RunId on EnvironmentId "1" from the RunTable is "3".  Likewise, the most recent run for EnvironementId "2" was RunId "6"

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the max runid for each environmentid from the runtable. Join the obtained result to the issuetable and select the required columns.

```
select i.id, i.runid, i.value, r.environmentid
from (select environmentid, max(runid) maxrunid
      from runtable 
      group by environmentid) r
join issuetable i on i.runid = r.maxrunid
order by i.runid, i.id
```

Answer (score 3):

These days one can use the analytical functions like RANK, DENSE_RANK, ROW_NUMBER to generate some ranking of your records.

Window functions are part of the ANSI SQL:2003 standard.
And I've at least encountered them on TeraData, [Oracle](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-analytic.html) and SQL-Server.

```
select Id, RunId, Value, EnvironmentId
from (
  select i.*, r.EnvironmentId,
  dense_rank() over (partition by r.EnvironmentId order by r.RunId desc) as RN
  from issuetable i
  inner join runtable r on (i.RunId = r.RunId)
) Q
where RN = 1
order by Id;
```

The inner query would yield the following results :

```
Id  RunId   Value   EnvironmentId   RN
1   1       10      1               2
2   1       20      1               2
3   1       30      1               2
4   2       40      3               1
5   2       50      3               1
6   3       60      1               1
7   4       70      2               2
8   5       80      4               1
9   6       90      2               1
```

Comment: Window functions were introduced in SQL:2003, not 1999. and DB2, Postgres, Firebird and several others also support them

Comment: Indeed, the article I found made me wrongfully assume the wrong standard for those functions. Thanks for pointing it out. It's been corrected it in the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that `ROW_NUMBER()` is the only one of the suggested methods that ensures exactly one row per group (partition) even if there are multiple occurrences of the MAX value -- and also makes it easy to use other fields  as a tie-breaker in the ORDER BY clause.